# How to configuring bandwidth switching on Pfsense

Tags: switching

I have to two Offices sharing  6 Megabytes internet link - the Main office has 4 Megabyte and the small office has 2 Megabytes but the users in the small office travel a lot and most of the time they are not in the office and I would like to configure on Pfense in such a way that if there are not users in the small office their allocated bandwidth will be used by in the main office

When the users in the small office their 2 Megabytes will be switch back to them

Is this feasible and how can configure it on Pfsense ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this because I haven't done anything like this myself but have you tried looking into schedules? I'm aware that you can use schedules when implementing firewall rules so it's possible that they can be used for bandwidth allocation as well. I will alter this post after some more investigation.